# Find cohorts in dataset in r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to find the biggest cohort in a dataset of about 1000 candidates and 100 test questions. Every candidate is asked 15 questions out of a pool of 100 test questions. People in different cohorts make the same set of randomly sampled questions. I'm trying to find the largest group of candidates who all make the same test.

I'm working in R. The data.frame has about a 1000 rows, and 100 columns. Each column indicates which test question we're working with. For each row (candidate) all column entries are NA apart from the ones where a candidate filled in a particular question he or she was shown. The input in these question instances are either 0 or 1. (see picture)

Is there an elegant way to solve this? The only thing I could think of was using dplyer and filter per 15 question subset, and check how many rows still remain. However, with 100 columns this means it has to check (i think) 15 choose 100 different possibilities. Many thanks!

[data.frame structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPBx7.png)

Comment: Welcome. Please share your data using ``dput(data)`` and don't share images of data/code - it makes it much easier for people to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can infer the cohort based on the NA pattern:

```r
library(tidyverse)

answers <- tribble(
  ~candidate, ~q1, ~q2, ~q3,
  1,0,NA,NA,
  2,1,NA,NA,
  3,0,0,00
)
answers
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   candidate    q1    q2    q3
#>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1         1     0    NA    NA
#> 2         2     1    NA    NA
#> 3         3     0     0     0

# infer cohort by NA pattern
cohorts <-
  answers %>%
  group_by(candidate) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), NA, TRUE)) %>%
  unite(-candidate, col = "cohort")
cohorts
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   candidate [3]
#>   candidate cohort        
#>       <dbl> <chr>         
#> 1         1 TRUE_NA_NA    
#> 2         2 TRUE_NA_NA    
#> 3         3 TRUE_TRUE_TRUE

answers %>%
  pivot_longer(-candidate) %>%
  left_join(cohorts) %>%
  # count filled answers per candidate and cohort
  group_by(cohort, candidate) %>%
  filter(! is.na(value)) %>%
  count() %>%
  # get the largest cohort
  arrange(-n) %>%
  pull(cohort) %>%
  first()
#> Joining, by = "candidate"
#> [1] "TRUE_TRUE_TRUE"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Danloo, thanks for the quick reply! The problem is that I don't have a table matching candidates to cohorts and that I'm trying to find the cohorts retroactively. But thinking about it, this seems like an impossible task.

Comment: Can we assume that all candidates with the same NA pattern are of the same cohort? e.g. all candidates filled always either 0 or 1. This is not the case in my example, because candidate 2 did not answer question 2.

Comment: yes we can assume that

Comment: Ok. I revised my answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton!